# How to access the router from winthin a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'd like to show a modal when `/url/confirm/` is requested.

This is what've done so far:

```
// footer component
import Modal from '../Modal/Modal';

export default {
    components: {Modal,},
    data() {
        return {
            showModal: false,
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        if (window.location.href.match('/confirm/')) {
             this.showModal = true;
        }
    },
};


// my main js
import MyFooter from './components/footer/MyFooter;
import router from './router';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,

    components: {MyFooter, /* other components too */}
});
```

And I combined with this https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes to cover all use cases?

This works but does not seem to be a vue way to do things, especially that I do the same thing in two different files.

How do I detect a `/confirm/` route whose name is `confirm` in vue in order to display the modal from within my component footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the route object](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html) (available inside components as `this.$route`):

```
if (this.$route.name == 'confirm') {
  this.showModal = true;
}
```

Comment: Thx but this works only if I refresh the page `/confirm/`, otherwhise I need to watch `'$route' (to, from)` as well, isn't there a way to do both in one place?

Comment: Just make `showModal` a computed property. `showModal() { return this.$route.name == 'confirm' }`